# Extraer url de un header usando bash script

Tags: bash, regex

Tengo ya bastante tiempo intentando extraer parte de un texto (un header) en `bash script` pero no lo he logrado, esto es lo que tengo:

```
link: <https://api.some.com/v1/monitor/zzsomeLongIdzz?access_token=xxSomeLongTokenxx==>; rel="monitor",<https://api.some.com/v1/services/xx/something-more/accounts/2345?access_token=xxSomeLongTokenxx==>; rel="parent"
```

Acá con un poco de formato para que lo puedan ver mejor

```
link: 
<https://api.some.com/v1/monitor/zzsomeLongIdzz?access_token=xxSomeLongTokenxx==>; 
rel="monitor",
<https://api.some.com/v1/services/xx/something-more/accounts/2345?access_token=xxSomeLongTokenxx==>; 
rel="parent"
```

Necesito la segunda parte, sólo la `url`, básicamente los valores entre `,<` y `>; rel="parent"` y asignarle eso a una variable, algo como:

```
my_url = $(echo $complete_header) <== aplicarle alguna forma de filtro
```

No tengo idea de cómo aplicarle un patrón o regex para extraer la data que necesito. Antes he usado `jq` para filtrar `json`, algo como:

```
error_message=$(echo $response | jq '.["errors"]|.[0]|.["message"]')
```

Desafortunadamente para mí esto no es `json`.

¿Alguien puede ayudarme a ir en la dirección correcta a mi pregunta?

Si la solución fuera con regex me gustaría que me pudieran dar un resumen de lo que significa dicho regex, lo suficiente para poder modificarlo.

Comment: ¿Necesitas ambas URLs? Es decir, ¿todas las URLs que aparecene en la cabecera?

Comment: Sólo la segunda, es decir el `parent`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He puesto la cabecera en un archivo `header` que contiene tu ejemplo:

```
$ cat header
link: <https://api.some.com/v1/monitor/zzsomeLongIdzz?access_token=xxSomeLongTokenxx==>; rel="monitor",<https://api.some.com/v1/services/xx/something-more/accounts/2345?access_token=xxSomeLongTokenxx==>; rel="parent"
```

Usando `--only-matching`, `--perl-regexp` y aserciones *lookbehind* y *lookahead* ([Advanced Grep Topics](http://caspar.bgsu.edu/~courses/Stats/Labs/Handouts/grepadvanced.htm)):

```
$ cat header | grep --only-matching --perl-regexp "(?<=,\<)(.*?)(?=\>; rel=\"parent\")"
```

Se obtiene:

```
https://api.some.com/v1/services/xx/something-more/accounts/2345?access_token=xxSomeLongTokenxx==
```

En tu bash script:

```
my_url = $(echo $complete_header | grep --only-matching --perl-regexp "(?<=,\<)(.*?)(?=\>; rel=\"parent\")")
```

Creo que para tu caso específico podría funcionar muy bien.